# Setting background image in h:commandbutton from CSS is not working

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

Setting a body background image from external CSS is working fine : The code for it is :
`background: url('../Images/BG.jpg') repeat;`

Now I have a command button on UI :

```
h:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="buttonClass"
```

The external CSS for buttonClass is :
    

       `.buttonClass {

     background: green url('../Images/buttonBG1.jpg') repeat;

     height : 30px;

     width: 150px;

     font-size: 20px;

     font-weight: bold;

     border: solid 5px;

     height: 30px;

       }`

This doesn't work. But when the same styling is done in CSS-inline, it works perfectly.It's able to add the image also. But when trying from the external CSS file, it doesn't work. What might be the problem?

Comment: check path, based on `url` your _css_ and _Images_ folders should be on the same level (subfolders of the same folder)

Comment: Path is correct, it works for other jsf components but it doesn't work for command button.

Comment: Open FireBug and check what styles are attached, what problems are there.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML is wrong: where it reads

```
h:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="buttonClass"
```

it should be

```
h:commandButton value="Login" class="buttonClass"
```